# Ctrl click in eclipse indigo doesn't open linked pages

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo

Can anyone tell me how to make eclipse indigo open linked page?
I mean that when i point cursor over the line like this:

```
<ui:include src="/pages/processes/editProcess.xhtml"/>
```

and press Ctrl+click i am moved to corresponding page. This happens in eclipse 3.5, but not in 3.7. Why? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reason is that path to page is invalid.

Comment: No, path is absolutely correct. Besides, as i said, this works fine in eclipse 3.5. Same project, same pages (there are a lot of pages, more than 100), but different eclipse versions.

Comment: check binding for .xhtml file

Comment: Well, i've found out a problem. My pages were opened by default in jsp editor not in html editor and jsp editor for some reason doesn't support such linking. So i've checked html editor as default and everything works now. Thank you!